# Automatically mirror display when docking or second monitor installed

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop that I move back and forth between field and office a lot. At my office I have a docking station with various peripherals attached to it (screen, keyboard, LAN, mouse, etc).

My laptop and my desk screen both support the same resolution, 1920x1080, and I pretty much never need a different resolution or screen attached.

Now, the annoying thing is that I have to set up the desktop screen every time: 
1. Set screens to mirror
2. Correct resolution for laptop screen
3. Correct resolution for desktop screen (for some reason, it goes to 1680x1050 every time i set it to mirror)

Isn't there a way to detect if the dock is attached, and then set the screen parameters automatically?

---

As means of detecting the dock, I've found that the output of `lsusb` could be useful. This is how it looks without the dock:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS Fingerprint sensor
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And with the dock and its peripherals attached:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05e3:0743 Genesys Logic, Inc. SDXC and microSDXC CardReader
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05e3:0743 Genesys Logic, Inc. SDXC and microSDXC CardReader
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0424:5537 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 0d8c:0170 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 05e3:0727 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 05e3:0727 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0424:2137 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS Fingerprint sensor
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see, the detection should be fairly straight forward, I can hack that part together with perl.

However, how do I then set the screen mirroring and resolution via command line?

**Software:**

- Linux Mint 18, XFCE

**Hardware:**

- Laptop: Toshiba Portege Z30-C-10W
- Dock: Toshiba Hi-Speed III
- Screen: Samsung 24" LED S24F350H

Is there a better way than writing a detection script and setting the parameters from command line somehow?